# It is possible to implement a ListView without XML files?

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter, listview-adapter

I'm trying to implement a `ListView` on my app, but i'm trying to understand and learn how to achieve it without using XML files, all with java code.

I'm stuck on the inflater part, the `mInflater.inflate();` function needs a resource xml file, so, i didn't understand how to continue without using XML files

I have a `ArrayList` of strings, and I simply need a `ListView` that shows a list with these strings of the `Arraylist`, and a delete `Button` on the right of the `String`. If the user press the `Button`, the item of the `List` get's deleted.

Each item of the `ListView` has two things, a `TextView` with the `String` of the `ArrayList` and a `Button` to delete it.

If someone can give me code examples i will be grateful.

Thanks

Comment: "i'm trying to understand and learn how to achieve it without using XML files, all with java code" -- why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I totally agree with CommonsWare. But the part that you are stuck is the part that you have to create a row "template" for the `ListView` rows. The `inflater` is used so as to make a single `View` out of a complete `layout.xml` file. So the basic idea is that you create an xml that represents each row and then inflate it through that piece of code.

In your situation, you need to do that through code. Perhaps add a `LinearLayout` as a parent with orientation=vertical add some width or height properties and then add 2 `TextView`s so as to be a title and a subtitle with some additional properties. Then you should add them to the `LinearLayout` and you there you go.

Your `LinearLayout` is a pile of `View`s that are dynamically created and have the same effect as inflating all the above code through an xml file.

But I reaaaaally don't see the point in creating such a fuss over a much faster, easier, straight forwarded, better implemented and not to mention best practice...

EDIT: Somewhere inside your adapter you have: `mInflater.inflate();` with the resource that you mention. As I previously said the resource determines how the "template" for each row would be. So a normal xml file that will determine a list row would be something like this:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical" >
   <TextView ... /> <! --some properties you want to set -->
   <TextView ... /> <! --some properties you want to set -->
</LinearLayout>
```

This xml produces a 2 line list row for a `ListView`. With the layout inflater the above xml file returns a `View` object that contains all the bundle.

So if you want to create it from code, then the snippet would be:

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context);
//layout set some properties
TextView title = new TextView(context);
//title set some properties
TextView subtitle = new TextView(context);
//subtitle set some properties
layout.add(title);
layout.add(subtitle);
```

Now instead of inflating the xml to get the contents into a single `View` object, you have the `layout` variable in the code snippet that contains all the logic that was previously inflated through the xml.

If you have created a custom `ListView` adapter before then you should be familiar with creating a custom list row and how it works.

EDIT: sample code for the adapter of the `ListView`

this is the standart procedure of `getView()` method of the adapter by inflating a single layout:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewgroup) {
ViewHolder holder; //our view holder of the row
if (view == null) {
   view = context.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.static_layout, null);
   holder = new ViewHolder();
   //set the views of the holder
       view.setTag(holder);
} else {
   holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
}
    //rest of implementation of the View
    return view;
}
```

dynamic implementation:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewgroup) {
ViewHolder holder; //our view holder of the row
if (view == null) {
       LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context);
       //layout set some properties
       TextView title = new TextView(context);
       //title set some properties
       TextView subtitle = new TextView(context);
       //subtitle set some properties
       layout.add(title);
       layout.add(subtitle);
   //CREATING THE LAYOUT THROUGH CODE

       view = layout; //INSTEAD OF INFLATING A LAYOUT FOR THE ROW I JUST BINDED IT TO THE RECENTLY CREATED LAYOUT 
   holder = new ViewHolder();
   //bind the views of the holder to the views of the layout
       view.setTag(holder);
} else {
   holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
}
    //rest of implementation of the View
    return view;
}
```

Comment: ¿add a LinearLayout as a parent? how can i do that in a adapter?

Comment: @Pableras84: You are also going to need to add in all of the configuration checks, to make sure you are applying the right Java code for your small screens in portrait, your small screens in landscape, your normal screens in portrait, your normal screens in landscape, your large screens in portrait, your large screens in landscape, your xlarge screens in portrait, and your xlarge screens in landscape. The reason why you are not seeing many samples taking this approach is because very few people would do it this way.

Comment: +1 CommonsWare. @Pableras84 I mean that you have to create your custom layout of a single row. What elements each row would have. And I made an example.

Comment: 10s, please, explain me how to add this layout to the adapter, i can't find the way. I can't use the inflate function, code example to doing it will be grated. CommonsWare, this app is only portrait, and when i create layouts with java, i use allways percentajes of the screen size, i only need to fit one screen, and this screen fits all the size of screens.

Comment: 10s, you said: "Now instead of inflating the xml to get the contents into a single View object, you have the layout variable in the code snippet that contains all the logic that was previously inflated through the xml." But you didn't explain how can Pableras84 tell the adapter that the layout variable is the variable that must hold the data.... and i dont understand how to do it. With XML is with the inflate function, but...¿how to do it with java code and the "layout" variable instead of a XML file?

Comment: Yes, please, 10s, explain me how to make my "layout" variable to hold the data of the listview

Comment: Because I don't quite understand what seems to be the problem I added 2 sample codes, one with the implementation of inflating the layout(according to most sample codes on the web) and one with the implementation of creating the row layout through code.